# Replace values < 2 by something else

Tags: python, pandas

After a : `df['A'].value_counts()`

How can I replace all the values < 2 by for example "Others"

To have after it for example a line named "Others = 8"

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example input and desired output in a complete form and not as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

1. Use groupby to group over column `A` and transform the column by its `count`, which is same as value counts but has same number of rows as original data
2. Use `lt(2)` which is less that 2 to get a boolean series
3. Update the column `A` for those indexes with the value `others`

```
idx = df.groupby(['A'])['A'].transform('count').lt(2)
df.loc[idx, 'A'] = 'others'
```

Edited with the `loc` as suggested by @Henry. Thanks!

Comment: The reference reliant subsetting is potentially unsafe here as either `df['A']` or `df['A'][idx]` could be a copy instead of view. `df.loc[idx, 'A'] = 'others'` would be safer.

Comment: agreed, made the change. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean mask and `append`:

```
out = df['A'].value_counts()
m = out < 2

out[~m].append(pd.Series(out[m].sum(), index=['Others']))
```